# can i use a keyword as a propertyname in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have to serialize/deserialize a class into a JSON string/and return. The JSON Strinig must contain the "error" string (like: {error:"something strange occoured", id:23, result:"xxxxx"}), which specifies the occoured error.

How can i implement a class like:

```
Public Class JsonResponse
    Public result As JsonResult
    Public error As String
    Public id As Integer
 End Class
```

If i do this, the word 'error' is invalid.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surround it with square brackets

```
Public Class JsonResponse
    Public result As JsonResult
    Public [error] As String
    Public id As Integer
 End Class
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Use [] around the name:

```
Public Class JsonResponse
   Public result As JsonResult
   Public [error] As String
   Public id As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: what are the [] doing exactly?

Comment: They allow you to use reserved words for method, class or member names.

For more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa711644

They're not intended for general use but for situations exactly like the one you have were there isn't much of an alternative.